# Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (11) in /home/aa/public_html/bb/db.php on line 2
Could not connect:

iam getting this error but the problem is that this error comes irregularly,sometimes it didnt come all the day and sometimes it comes countless times.

what could be the possible reason for this?????

Comment: i dont think there's any such problem because if there had been any such connectivity error then my database should not get connected even once.But my database is getting connected successfully but sometimes this error starts coming in.So i wanted to know the possible reason of this kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

That could mean that MYSQL is down or you use the wrong host name while connect. One more possible reason for that could be difference in socket configuration of php against mysql, you can check it in by looking at entry socket in mysql config. file and by looking at output of phpinfo(), you need just to compare it. Or it could that someone else on your machine also using that socket.

PS. As well my wild guess, go through your code and check you always get your connection close right and all your queries as well.

Comment: -1: error message gives the file path - so nothing to do with network

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your MySQL is running.
OR
Create a file called: **phpinfo.php** with the following inside it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load the file in your browser: **http://localhost/phpinfo.php** and scroll down for **mysql**. Look for the **MYSQL_SOCKET** and make sure it matches your entry in your **my.cnf file**.

FYI, my my.cnf file is located in: **/etc/my.cnf** and it contains something like this:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Nearly right - putting the socket in /tmp is very silly - by default files in tmp are only readable for their owners. But both mysql and php need to be using the same file, file must exist, and must be rw for both.